# Logged-in mandatory controller in Codeigniter fails on server

Tags: php, codeigniter

Using Codeigniter, I have certain controllers that correspond to the logged-in section of my site.

Each of these controllers is defined like that:

```
class Account extends MY_Controller { ... }
```

Where MY_Controller is a core extension of CI_Controller and this is the full code:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {   
        parent::__construct();

        if(!$this->session->userdata('loggedIn')) { //Not logged in
            $this->session->set_userdata('frontend_redirect' , current_url()); //record the URL post-login
            $this->output->set_status_header('401'); //Unauthorized HTTP header
            redirect('app/login'); die();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically if the user is not logged in, it saves the requested page, redirects to the login page (which will redirect to the requested page again once logged in).

That works perfectly fine locally on WAMP. But on a real server if the user is not logged in it shows a blank page and doesn't redirect to the login page at all.

Any ideas why? I'm assuming the 401 status header may be the cause.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have PHP errors turned on on your server?  Often, if you get a blank page, it's because their is a PHP error and error-reporting is turned off. I know you said it works on WAMP, but your server may differ in PHP versions, etc.

Comment: Yep errors are turned on. Nothing breaks, it just doesn't redirect. Both wamp and the server have php 5.3 and I haven't been able to isolate something in php.ini or other that would be the cause.